# Is the <map> element supported in Safari 9?

Tags: html, css, safari

Is the HTML `<map>` element supported in Safari 9? It works perfectly fine in Safari 8 and according to http://caniuse.com/ should be supported by all major browsers.

But in my case, it is not working in Safari 9? Is that a general issue?

// Not working meaning: hover over the section doesn't change cursor to pointer and click doesn't take me to the target page (no action at all). In other browsers I can see the cursor pointer, link target in the bottom left corner of the browser and click takes me to the target page.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="hero">
    <img id="desktop-hero-image" usemap="desktop-large" src="//cdn.myimg.com/img.jpg">
    <map name="desktop-large">
        <area shape="rect" coords="505,211,701,246" href="https://www.myurl.com" alt="LUXE"><area shape="rect" coords="720,211,905,246" href="https://www.myurl.com" alt="ALL CANDLES">
    </map>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Edited my question @TylerH

Comment: Are you sure it does work in other browsers ? It seems you forgot the leading `#` in the `<img>`'s `usemap` attribute.

Comment: Okay, so I figured it out now: as I used JS to dynamically measure the screen size and change the `usemap` accordingly and the ones added by JS were without `#`. Although, still remains the question why it worked in other browsers w/o `#`.